# Auto shrink label with multiple lines Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am making a app without using storyboard. The app has a long text so I can't get enought space on one line. The app is for both iPad and iPhone. The `adjustSizeToFit = true` does not work, is there a metode to adjust size of label with multiple lines?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your issue? I'm not quite getting what it is that you want help with. You got a width in there, you also specified number of lines. What exactly are you trying to accomplish that you need help with?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no property on `UILabel` called `adjustSizeToFit`. Are you sure you didn't mean `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`? Which if you look at the documentation, says:

> Normally, the label text is drawn with the font you specify in the font property. If this property is set to true, however, and the text in the text property exceeds the label’s bounding rectangle, the receiver starts reducing the font size until the string fits or the minimum font size is reached. In iOS 6 and earlier, this property is effective only when the numberOfLines property is set to 1.

Which I'm not sure is what you wanted.

If you wanted a `UILabel` with an arbitrary number of lines, where the text is contained within a certain width, continue reading:

What you do will depend on whether you're using AutoLayout or not:

**Not AutoLayout**

Just use:

```
let size = label.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: myWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
// CGFloat.max, because we don't want to limit the UILabel's height.
label.frame.size = size
```

**AutoLayout**

Firstly, you should set `numberOfLines` to zero. 
Secondly, you need to tell AutoLayout how long each line can be, this **doesn't** default to the width of the label. For this you need a `UILabel` subclass:

```
class myLabel : UILabel {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // 1. Get the label to set its frame correctly:
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // 2. Now the frame is set we can get the correct width 
        // and set it to the preferredMaxLayoutWidth.
        self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.width
    }
}
```

Comment: I am making the button programmely. How do i connect it to the class?

Comment: You didn't mention any button in your original question. I would recommend either creating a new question or there are plenty of resources online. Hope that helps.

Comment: It doesn't appear like there is an equivalent for SKLabel?

Comment: I don't believe there is an equivalent. However you could always add a `UILabel` to your `SKScene`'s view, which you would remove when moving from the scene :)